# Storing List data in Hbase?

Tags: java, python, list, arraylist, hbase

Im trying to store a list,collection of data objects in Hbase. For example ,a User table where a the userId is the Rowkey and column family Contacts with column Contacts:EmailIds where EmailIds is a list of emails as

```
{abcd@example.com,bpqrs@gmail.com....etc}
```

How do we model this in Hbase ? How do we do this in Java?/Python?Ive tried pickling and unpickling data in Python but this is one solution which I do not want to use due to performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it in the following manner:

```
| userid | contacts                                              |
| test   | c:email1=test@example.com; c:email2=te.st@example.com |
```

or

```
| userid | contacts                                              |
| test   | c:test@example.com=1; c:te.st@example.com=2           |
```

This way you can use versioning, add/remove as much email addresses as you want, use filters, and it is really easy to iterate over these KV pairs in the client code

Comment: but what would be a good approach for storing a collection of complex records, i.e. records that have multiple fields? For example, addresses each having a city, state, etc.